# How to navigate a webpage from listbox (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I have a listbox with some items in it previously added, these items are urls so I want when I double click an item in this listbox the webbrowser to navigate to it.

Here's what I tried:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox1.SelectedItem);
```

but it shows up some errors I can't understand, Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: "Shows up some errors". Shall we guess what those errors are?

Comment: No, sorry for that. It gives me 2 errors at startup, it's not something that doesn't work when I try to do it. The errors are: -Unable to convert from object to string -The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(string)' has some invalid arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have to give full url of the site with `http` or `https`, for example

```
//Fine
webBrowser1.Navigate("https://www.google.lk");

//Error
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.lk");
```

So make sure you pass the qualified url to the `Navigate()` method. Also you can't directly use `SelectedItems` property use the following code,

```
webBrowser1.Navigate(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

Comment: It gives me 2 errors at startup, it's not something that doesn't work when I try to do it. The errors are:
-Unable to convert from object to string
-The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.Navigate(string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: You can't directly use selecteditems, see my edited answer. make sure MultiSelect property is disabled for the ListView

Comment: I'm using a listbox and it doesn't recognise .Text. Does this method works on listview?

Comment: @user2359928 If its listBox you have to use ToString() check my updated answer. let me know if it works.

Comment: It worked. Thank you so much. You made my day. I really needed this to go on making my software :)

Comment: @user2359928 Please mark it as answer if it helped. It will help others to find the right answer